# Overriding a method contract in an extended interface that uses generics (Java)?

Tags: java, generics, interface, polymorphism, overriding

I am attempting to override a method declaration within an interface that extends another interface. Both of these interfaces use generics. According to the Java tutorials, this should be possible, but the example does not use generics. When I try to implement it, the compiler shows the following error (I've replaced names because some of the code is not my own.):

> myMethod(T) in InterfaceExtended
>   clashes with myMethod(T) in Interface;
>   both methods have the same erasure,
>   but neither overrides the other.

Code looks like this:

```
public interface Interface<T>
{
public void myMethod(T x);
}

public interface ExtendedInterface<T> extends Interface<T>
{
public void myMethod(T x);
}
```

If anyone has suggestions as to how to alter this to make it acceptable, or an explanation regarding the reason this is causing a problem, I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks!

badPanda

Comment: Just don't override the method.  It adds nothing.

Comment: It is an assignment, which explicitly specifies I must. If it was my own code, I wouldn't....

Comment: Interesting...what IDE are you using? I am using IntelliJ, with Java 1.6 - 7.

Comment: did you cut and paste your code or retype it?  because your error message doesn't match your code (InterfaceExtended vs ExtendedInterface)

Comment: I completely retyped it because I felt it was necessary to use different names for the methods and interfaces, as one of the interfaces is not mine. Also, they are fairly complex and I simplified to the relevant code.

Comment: @Skip Head, I don't know if you're saying that Overriding methods in interface is useless, but [here is an example](http://ideone.com/okNVf) where the override could be useful.

Comment: So this is moderately embarrassing, but my problem had to do with a typo earlier in my code. I should know better than to be writing these things at 4 am >< Thanks to everyone for the help though; I understand the way that the code is working in much greater detail.

Comment: @Colin Hebert, Thanks for pointing that out. In the case given in the question it *is* useless though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want an overloaded version of myMethod? Then you should not use T twice, but like this:

```
public interface Interface<T>
{
  public void myMethod(T x);
}

public interface ExtendedInterface<T, V> extends Interface<T>
{
  public void myMethod(V x);
}
```

Now it is possible to have something like this:

```
class MyClass implements ExtendedInterface<String, Integer> {
  public void myMethod(String x) { .. }
  public void myMethod(Integer x) { .. }
}
```

Edit: interestingly enough, this also works (although it is useless):

```
class MyClass implements ExtendedInterface<String, String> {
  public void myMethod(String x) { .. }
}
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? In Java 1.6 under Eclipse this works correctly.

Comment: @badpanda, that's because you implemented twice the same interface

Answer (score 1):

This does work. You could have a problem if your class implements twice the same interface with two different generics types.

For example :

```
class MyClass implements Interface<String>, ExtendedInteface<Integer>{
}
```

For example [this code](http://ideone.com/UEJ5C) only fails on the third class.

And here is the message I have on IntelliJ X :
[image]