# Extend a generic interface and make it stricter in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

**TLDR:** I want to make a generic interface definition stricter after extension.

Let's say we've operations and request/response objects on which they can operate.

I've defined a base interface which mandates every operation should have **execute** method in it.

```
public interface Operation<S, T> {
    T execute(S request);
}
```

I want to extend it to bunch of other interface which are for specific operations. e.g.

```
public interface ReadOperation<S extends ReadRequest, T extends ReadResponse> extends Operations {
    T execute(S readRequest);
}
```

Typically I would want to *overwrite* the base interface **execute** definition with a stricter definition in extending interface. But unfortunately it's not achievable as java adds an overloaded method with new execute definition.

I want to understand where does my *intuition* lack and how in some other form I can achieve it. Tell me if I'm doing it horribly wrong.

Closest I could find here: [Overriding a method contract in an extended interface that uses generics (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961639)

Comment: What is your use case for this? It's not at all clear what this would be good for. Can you provide some usage examples?

Comment: @JimGarrison One of the usage should be clear above- I want to enforce execute to all types of operations but because of the nature of operation I want to have different types of bounded objects on which they can be operated upon. Does that make thing little clear or a concrete example would be more helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you're using a raw type. You don't provide a generic type to the extended `Operation` interface, so the compiler doesn't know that the `S` and `T` in each are meant to be the same. Change your `ReadOperation` to this:

```
public interface ReadOperation<S extends ReadRequest, T extends ReadResponse> extends Operation<S, T> {
    T execute(S readRequest);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks for the quick response.